# Add row to HTML Table at Run-time in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, html-table

I have an HTML table with `runat="server"` in asp.net.

I want to add row to the table On click event of a button or some thing like that, my table is like:

```
<table id="table1" runat="server"></table>
```

I tried `table1.InnerHtml = "<tr></td>Test</td></tr>";`

but it does not work and I get this exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'HtmlTable' does not support the InnerHtml property.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This maybe your answer in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bewx260%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a row to the table, and a cell to this row:

```
var row = new HtmlTableRow();
var cell = new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = "Test" };
row.Cells.Add(cell);
table1.Rows.Add(row);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the rows and cells explicitly:

Untested:

```
var newRow = new HtmlTableRow();
var newCell = new HtmlTableCell();

newCell.InnerText = "Test";

newRow.Cells.Add(newCell);

table1.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

Answer (score 1):

I Execute the above code in vb.net , and it creates a new row with text that i input in textbox, when i click button. but problem is that it only create one row, 
and alter the first row with new input on second click.
I need

```
<table id="Mytable" runat="server">
    <tr><td>Row Data 1.....!</td></tr>  //New row on 1st click
    <tr><td>Row Data 2.....!</td></tr>  //New row on 2nd click
    <tr><td>Row Data 3.....!</td></tr>  //New row on 3rd click
</table>
```

a New Row every time when i click button. How we can do this?